# Stop Unity from smoothening out images

Tags: unity, image

In Unity, low-resolution images are "smoothened out". Is there a way to keep them pixelated?

For your information, the images that I'll be using are in PNG format.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect is controlled by the Filter mode of the Image. You can change it in the Import settings.

To get a pixelated look, choose the option "Point (no filter)"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It so unusual but you may give a try to *Max Size* property of import settings.

- Select your picture (from Project explorer, not from Hierarchy).
- Set *Max Size* in inspector to lowest as much as you can.

[image]

Comment: Your answer led me to @user000user's answer which is the correct one. Props to you for your early reply: if I had more reputation points, I would upvote your answer.

Comment: If someone reads this, I suggest upvoting this answer.